# In which browsers is HTML5 parser fully supported?

Tags: html, cross-browser

The HTML5 parser's specification was released years ago, still I don't know if I can rely on it's implementations across browsers.

Example: we know that it's possible to omit quotes in attribute values to save our eyes and traffic:

```
<input type=text>
```

Of course, not always:

```
<span class="link red"></span>
```

According to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0), we can also omit quotes here (let's leave debates about readability):

```
<form enctype=multipart/form-data action=http://example.com:8080/form.php>
```

Quotation:

> attribute values must not contain any literal space characters, any U+0022 QUOTATION
>   MARK characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), "=" (U+003D)
>   characters, "<" (U+003C) characters, ">" (U+003E) characters, or "`"
>   (U+0060) characters, and must not be the empty string

But where can I find tests which prove that parser works in IE8, for example? I found that I'm not using new possibilities only because I'm scared it can break somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But where can I find tests which prove that parser works in IE8, for
>   example?

You will be surprised, but in IE8 only. Create jsfiddle and test it.

It not good to omit quotes. Especially for `our eyes and traffic`:

- Your eyes can save the IDE with good parsing
- You can minified you code, remove quoties, remove spaces, but only GZIP and Cache can really minified your traffic

And you will be surprised again, but `http://somesite.com/?search=Im a query string with space` is a valid URI and frequent case:

```
<form action="http://somesite.com/?search=Im a query string with space">
<input type="text" name="get_param" value="im_a_query_param_too">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This form can be using on user search page, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this site is what you are looking for: http://html5test.com/ It tests the supported features of your browser and let's you compare it to most other browsers.